# How to make pyautogui type a link in google as well as loop over a user-decided amount of times?

Tags: python, libraries

Am running this code, but it is not typing the kahoot link, it is only typing chrome. Here's the code:

```
import pyautogui as gui
import random
gui.FAILSAFE = False
pin = input('What is the kahoot code? ')
name = input('Pick a bot name, no numbers. ')
nums = input('Select the amount of bots. Maximum 100. ')
a = str(list(range(100)))
gui.move(-1000, 1000)
gui.click()
gui.write('Chrome')
gui.press('Enter')
for num in nums:
    x = random.choice(a)
    gui.write('Kahoot.it')
    gui.press('Enter')
    gui.write(pin)
    gui.press('Enter')
    gui.write(name + x)
    gui.press(enter)
    gui.keyDown('ctrl')
    gui.keyDown('t')
    gui.keyUp('ctrl')
    gui.keyUp('t')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the Chrome navigator isn't loaded when `pyautogui` starts to write. You should use `time.sleep` to wait a little bit while Chrome is loading. However, I think you should use the `selenium` package if you want to use the navigator, as it can manipulate it more precisely than `pyautogui`.

Hope it helped you.